# Turn off color inversion for marked pane in tmux

Tags: tmux

It appears that in *tmux*, when I mark a pane using `prefix-m`, the borders of that pane are displayed with inverted colors. By this I mean the foreground color is used for the background and the background color is used for the foreground.

I can't find any way to turn this off -- `man tmux` seems very sparse when it comes to information about marked panes. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source-code, apparently not.  The action proceeds unconditionally through these points:

- [`cmd_select_pane_exec`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/cmd-select-pane.c#L55) calls
- [`server_redraw_window_borders`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/server-fn.c#L122) which does
- [`c->flags |= CLIENT_BORDERS`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/server-fn.c#L129), and that is checked in
- [`server_client_check_redraw`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/server-client.c#L923), which then calls
- [`screen_redraw_screen`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/screen-redraw.c#L331), with its draw_borders parameter true, so it calls
- [`screen_redraw_draw_borders`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/screen-redraw.c#L398)

and in the last, it applies some style information but unconditionally reverses colors.

Comment: I've created [an issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/497) on the _tmux_ Github repository referencing this question and answer.

Comment: "No thanks. Given marked panes are meant to be transitory---that is, whilst performing a given command; an option for this seems overkill when the effect of the pane's border is for a short length of time only." So, it sounds like we will not be seeing this option soon, or ever.

Comment: If you came up with a simple, non-intrusive proposed change, they might consider that.  But they're probably viewing it as an unnecessary complication.